# How to covert time to TIMEZONE in oracle

Tags: oracle, timezone

I would like to know how to convert current time to TIMEZONE in oracle

I tried this and worked perfectly

```
SELECT (select tzname from qct_timezone_config tzc where gmtoffset = 
    (select usr_time_zone from qct_user_token where resource_id = 11385)) AS TIMEZONE,
  TO_CHAR(CAST(SYSTIMESTAMP AS TIMESTAMP WITH TIME ZONE) AT TIME ZONE
    (select tzname from qct_timezone_config tzc where gmtoffset = 
      (select usr_time_zone from qct_user_token where resource_id = 11385)),
    'DD-MON-RR HH:MI:SS.FF AM') AS USER_TIME
FROM dual
```

But what i want to know is what if the time '03-AUG-2017 11.00.00 AM' is sent from the other system (i want to convert this time to a specific TimeZone) and how to rewrite this query.

Comment: Which specific timezone - the value you're obtaining from `qct_timezone_config`? How are you getting the value from the other system - what mechanism, and as what data type? You should also at least include some sample data (from those tables if relevant) and expected result.

Answer (score 0):

You already have everthing in you query, to convert a timestamp to a specific timezone you have to use "AT TIME ZONE" precising the timezone you want your timestamp to be converted:

```
select systimestamp AT TIME ZONE 'America/Los_Angeles' "West Coast Time" from dual;
```

I'm not sure what you want to accomplish and the timestamp you want to convert needs to include a timezone if you want to convert it to another timezone.